# Openshift Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, openshift

I am looking for explanation for functions used in below Jenkins pipeline on openshift.

> 1. builds.untilEach(1)
> 2. it.describe()
> 3. echo "Inside loop: ${it}"
> 4. return (it.object().status.phase == "Complete")

```
node {
    stage('build') {
        openshift.withCluster() {
            openshift.withProject() {
              echo "Using project: ${openshift.project()}"
              def builds = openshift.selector("bc", "front-end-build").related('builds')
              builds.describe()
              timeout(5) { 
               1. builds.untilEach(1) {
                2.    it.describe()
                 3.   echo "Inside loop: ${it}"
                   4. return (it.object().status.phase == "Complete")
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more context? What are you trying to do with this pipeline? Can you re-phrase your question?

Comment: What is the meaning of the following lines: builds.untilEach(1) {
                                                                         it.describe()
                                                                          echo "Inside loop: ${it}"
                                                                          return (it.object().status.phase == "Complete")

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give an overview of what the lines you mentioned mean:

1. `timeout(5)` This means that the steps described within this part (between `{}`) need to finish within 5 minutes or else they will be terminated. This step will fail if any of the below actions take more than 5 minutes.
2. `builds.untilEach(1)` Loops over all Builds related to the selector `openshift.selector("bc", "front-end-build")` above. This loop expects at least one build to be returned. It loops over the Builds and waits until the closure body (between `{}`) returns "true".
3. `it.describe()` Describes the Build object that is currently being looped over / waited on.
4. `echo "Inside loop: ${it}"` Write the Build object to stdout.
5. `return (it.object().status.phase == "Complete")` Check if the Build that we are looping over is complete and return.

So basically, this loop will wait for all Builds related to the BuildConfig `front-end-build` to complete.